# BoxLayout stretches component to fit parent panel

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Hi I am using a `BoxLayout` to stack `JPanel`s on top of each other (`BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`), for example if my parent `JPanel` is of height 500 pixels and I add two child panels to it both of height 100 pixels. The `BoxLayout` stretches them so that together they occupy the the 500px space. Does anyone know how to disable this feature?

Comment: How are you sepcifying the size of the child panels?

Comment: With panel.setPrefferedSize and panel.setMinimumSize both using the same Dimension

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) instead. You have much more control over your UI.

But if you want to use BoxLayout still, and don't want them to stretch, you can check out using [invisible component fillers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) like rigid areas, glue and fillers.

Comment: If down voting me, please provide a reason

Comment: Be sure to check out the "Horizontal Glue" section in the link posted. Very helpful.

Answer (score 24):

BoxLayout is one of the few layout managers that respects the minimum and maximum sizes of a component. So if you want to prevent a panel from stretching you can use:

```
panel.setMaximumSize( panel.getPreferredSize() );
```

Comment: This may have been a while ago, but is that using an overridden getPreferredSize() method?

Comment: @MikeM, no, since the panel is relying on the layout manager to return the preferred size. Actually a better solution is to extend the JPanel and override the `getMaximumSize()` method to simply return the value from the `getPreferredSize()` method. This way the maximum size will be dynamically calculated in case the preferred size dynamically changes.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is, as the previous answer mentioned, to use the glue, fillers, and rigid areas in the box layout. Unlike that responder, though, I'd recommend sticking with BoxLayout - you can accomplish most simple UIs easier with Box than with the Grid Bag; and the extra power doesn't buy you much in your typical dialog box.

In the old idiom, these were things like Box.createHorizontalStrut(int x) and Box.createHorizontalGlue(); the idea is that you put a strut between your first and second components and then add a glue after the second one. ("strut" = "rigid area" nowadays).

Comment: I will agree with that for general stacking purposes the GridBagLayout may be overkill. Just suggesting it if he goes forward.

Comment: I have tried putting a rigid area between the two child panels and vertical glue after the second one, put the panels are still being stretched :s

Comment: There is no such thing as an overkill :)

Comment: Try adding a panel container for the bottom 2 panels, then sticking those two themselves in a box... I'm not clear on the arrangement you're looking for, but you can always come up with some combination of subpanels, struts, and glue that makes things not stretch.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work perfectly fine... using BoxLayout, as you wanted.

[image: test]

```
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // this being the JFrame

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    panel.setBackground(Color.orange);
    this.add(panel); // add the parent to the JFrame

    JPanel pnlChild1 = new JPanel();
    pnlChild1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    pnlChild1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    JPanel pnlChild2 = new JPanel();
    pnlChild2.setBackground(Color.magenta);
    pnlChild2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    panel.add(pnlChild1);
    panel.add(pnlChild2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your panels are stretching because BoxLayout does not constrain each panel to its preferred size. You need to find layouts that do respect a component's preferred size, as BorderLayout's NORTH and SOUTH positions do.

Try this:

1. Create a JPanel with a BorderLayout. Add your child component as NORTH in this JPanel.
2. Create a second JPanel for the other child component, add it as NORTH of a BorderLayout
3. Add the two JPanels to your BoxLayout.

Code:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel1.add(component1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel2.add(component2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

JPanel boxPanel = new JPanel();
BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(boxPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
boxPanel.setLayout(boxLayout);
boxPanel.add(panel1);
boxPanel.add(panel2);
```

Comment: I like this solution because it avoids messing with gridbag and modifying the components themselves both of which is a great plus.