# Valign JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, boxlayout

I am trying to align JPanel vertically. setAlignmentY is not working as expected.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ValignJPanel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vertical Alignment");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel1 = wrapPanel(createPanel(), Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel panel2 = wrapPanel(createPanel(), Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel panel3 = wrapPanel(createPanel(), Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.add(panel3);

        frame.setSize(400, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel wrapPanel(JPanel oldPanel, float alignment) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        oldPanel.setAlignmentY(alignment);
        panel.add(oldPanel);
        return panel;
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello world"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(10));
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
        return panel;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a wrapper method which takes JPanel & wraps it as given alignment.

EDIT (from comment, with image) I am trying to get output which looks like this, but in place of button, i want to have JPanel

[image]

Comment: Stop editing your post, now it doesn't compile. If your going to edit it make sure it compiles first.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to align?

Comment: Sorry for post edit. I am trying to align JPanel that I can get from createPanel(). In the above example, I am trying to get 3 JPanels valigned at top, center & bottom.

Comment: So you want them to be jagged, horizontally?

Comment: Vertically.. First panel at top, second at middle & last at bottom..

Comment: these 3 panels are put horizontally just for comparison.

Comment: I am trying to get output which looks like this, but in place of button, i want to have JPanel
www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/XAxisAlignment.htm

Comment: See my updated answer. I'm still trying to figure out the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is set the layout to `BoxLayout` for the `new JPanel` in the `wrapPanel` method.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
panel.setLayout(layout);
```

**Bug:** With your current code It doesn't seem to work because it'll stretch the text field. If you use a `JButton` in place of the `JTextFeild` you will see the effect. I'm still trying to figure out why the text field does that.

---

**UPDATE** Along with the above code, to fix the problem of the text field stretching, as answered by Camickr in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196699/2587435)

> `BoxLayout` is one of the few layout managers that respects the minimum and maximum sizes of a component. So if you want to prevent a panel from stretching you can use:

```
panel.setMaximumSize( panel.getPreferredSize() );
```

The above code is what you want to put in the `createPanel` method.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class ValignJPanel {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vertical Alignment");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel1 = wrapPanel(createPanel(), Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel panel2 = wrapPanel(createPanel(), Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel panel3 = wrapPanel(createPanel(), Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);
        frame.add(panel3);
        frame.setSize(400, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel wrapPanel(JPanel oldPanel, float alignment) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        oldPanel.setAlignmentY(alignment);
        panel.add(oldPanel);
        return panel;
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello world"));
        panel.add(new JTextField(10));
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.setMaximumSize( panel.getPreferredSize());
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I was out yesterday. Sorry for delayed answer acceptance.